# Get the specific value of the_meta() in WordPress?

Tags: php, wordpress, meta

I'm trying exhaustively to get a specific row from within a loop using the_meta() array in Wordpress and assigning a variable to it (like the procedural while loop). Right now it simply pulls all of the rows at once. The result from this query returns 3 rows from the database. What I am trying to do it wrap a div tag around one of the returned rows that is stored within the_meta();.

I've tried exploding the array and returning the first row but it just returns everything all at once. I just want to get a row and put it in a variable so that I can style it using CSS.

Here is the code:

```
$args = array( 
'post_type' => 'membersprofile', 
'posts_per_page' => 20);        

$loop = new WP_Query( $args );

    while ( $loop->have_posts() ) : $loop->the_post();  

$newvar = explode(" ", the_meta());
echo $newvar[0];

endwhile;
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated!

EDIT: Thanks to Youn for pointing me in the right direction and finding the answer for me, The problem was I was using the_meta() which only returned the whole rows. By using get_post_meta I was able to assign variables to each row returned. The code that works is:

```
$key_2_value = get_post_meta(get_the_ID(), 'wpcf-shortbio', true);

// check if the custom field has a value
if($key_2_value != '') {
    echo $key_2_value;
}
```

Hope this helps someone else!

Comment: you mean by using $var=get_post_meta() as described in http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta ? the_meta() does not store the meta in a variable, it just displays it

Comment: haha @YounElan thank you so much for pointing me in the right direction!!!! I've managed to do as you said and use the get_post_meta. Now I can split the rows into variables. Thank you so much I really appreciate your fast response :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try using get_post_meta() in place of the meta. It will return the meta value for a specific page/post.

For more info visit at http://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/get_post_meta

Comment: thank you , i can show mycustom  meta field in my theme's single page (content-single.php)  <div class="entry-meta">
   page <?php get_metadata('post', the_ID(), 'page_number', true); ?>
  </div>

Answer (score 2):

In loop you can use

```
<?php if (have_posts()) : ?>
<?php while (have_posts()) : the_post(); ?>
   <p><?php echo post_custom( 'my_meta_key' ) ; ?></p>
<?php  endwhile; endif; ?>
```